# Undo a Deletion on an activity

Tags: activity

I deleted an activity and would like to re-add it. Please help!
I can't seem to find a search bar that would help me find the right steps to correct.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you will find a process to undelete a deleted activity via the UI. If you have access to the database then you could try finding the relevant entry from the log_civicrm_activity and log_civicrm_activity_contact to reconstruct your missing item.